# str object has no attribute keys when attempting to write a dictionary to csv in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm converting a script that worked in Python 2.7 to Python 3 and I'm having issues with it. The script has two lists (idList and pageTitles) that are put together into a dictionary named idDict. When I do a print of the idDict, it appears properly with the two fields in a dictionary formatting. However, when I attempt to output this into a csv file, I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'. I cannot figure out why this dictionary is suddenly being considered as a string instead.

```
#Create a dictionary out to the two lists
idDict = dict(list(zip(idList,pageTitles))) 

with open ('csvfile', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames = headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(idDict)
```

Comment: Make a [mcve] with imports and values defined for `idList`, `pagetitles`, `headers` that produces the error claimed.

Comment: You don't need to call `list()` in the call to `dict()`.

Comment: The argument to `writerows()` is supposed to be a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary. If you're just writing one dictionary, use `writerow()`.

Comment: `writerows` takes a list of dicts, not a single dict, which is the cause of the error.  Show the desired input and output.

Comment: You have error because `headers` != `idList`

Comment: @dimay They don't have to be equal. `idList` can be a subset of `headers` and it'll work.

Comment: since you are converting an old (ancient by now) script to a contemporary one, I would suggest you to consider changing your variable names to be PEP-8 compatible, e.g. `id_dict` instead of `idDict` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writerows` should be a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary should have a number of entries that match your headers.

Working example:

```
idList=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
pageTitles=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
headers=['id','pagetitle']

#Create a dictionary out to the two lists
idDict = [{'id':v, 'pagetitle':pageTitles[i]} for i,v in enumerate(idList)]    

with open ('csvfile', 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames = headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(idDict)
```

That list comprehension line is producing the list of dictionaries that `writerows` is needing:

```
[{'id': 1, 'pagetitle': 'a'},
 {'id': 2, 'pagetitle': 'b'},
 {'id': 3, 'pagetitle': 'c'},
 {'id': 4, 'pagetitle': 'd'},
 {'id': 5, 'pagetitle': 'e'},
 {'id': 6, 'pagetitle': 'f'},
 {'id': 7, 'pagetitle': 'g'},
 {'id': 8, 'pagetitle': 'h'},
 {'id': 9, 'pagetitle': 'i'},
 {'id': 10, 'pagetitle': 'j'}]
```

Comment: The line to create the dictionary was the main source of my issue it turns out. Once I took your example and put it in there, it worked. Thank you!